# BigQuery SDK TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: google-bigquery

I am quite new to Google API. But I ran this code once on my AI notebook and worked and when I restarted the kernel and ran it again I got the error that you see.
I googled and people were talking about versions, etc. but it was working before I restarted the Kernel.

```
job = bqclient.query(query, retry=bq_retry.DEFAULT_RETRY)
```

Error:

> TypeError: **init**() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Are you suing Python? If yes, which version?

Comment: yes, 3.7..I tried the Python shell in terminal and it worked.

Comment: Do you still have the same problem with AI Notebook or is your problem solved?

Comment: I started a new Kernel and worked. But in that Kernel still doesnt. I moved on.